# How to fix that. Cannot find name 'styled'.ts(2304)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react"
import { BiRegistered } from "react-icons/bi";
import { LoginLabel } from "../../src/components/Account/Login/LoginLabel";

const LabelCOntainer=styled.label``
export default function Register() {
  return (
      <form>
        <label >Nome Completo</label>
        <input/><br/>

        <label> E-mail:</label>
        <input/><br/>

        <input/></form>
  );
}
```

I don't know how to fix it, I need help to follow ahead!?

Comment: `import styled from "styled-components"` should do you (but you'll need to add `styled-components` to your dependencies if it's not there already).

Answer (score 0):

You have to import emotion, you can do like:

- Add the import on the top **import styled from "@emotion/styled";**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).